# Consider the ring $R=ℂ[X,Y]$ and the ideal $I=(X^2-Y,X^2+Y)$. We find (??) that $R/I ≅ℂ[X]/(X^2)$.

Tags: ring-theory

I'm trying to understand a step in an example of my reader about rings.

> Consider the ring $R=ℂ[X,Y]$ and the ideal $I=(X^2-Y,X^2+Y)$. We find
>   that $R/I ≅ℂ[X]/(X^2)$.

As the author doesn't give any more details of this step, I think the author thinks this step is obvious. However, it is not yet obvious to me.

I do know the following facts:

$$ℂ[X,Y] = (ℂ[X])[Y]$$ and $$R[X]/(X-a) ≅ R$$ where $a \in R$ and $R$ a commutative ring with idendity.

I've been trying for some time, but without succes. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can treat the polynomials in your ideal as equations identifying elements of $R$ with each other. Thus $X^2 = Y$ and $X^2 = -Y$. This means you can leave out $Y$ by substituting it with $X^2$ which in turn equals zero.

Comment: "You can treat the polynomials in your ideal as equations identifying elements of $R$ with each other." I don't understand what you mean with this sentence.

Comment: Quotienting by $X^2-Y$ means that you define new equalities where $p \thicksim q$ iff $p = q + r(X^2-Y)$. Hence you have that $X^2 - Y = 0$, i.e $X^2 = Y$. But you also quotient by $X^2+Y$, and hence $X^2 = -Y$ in the quotient. In the quotient, you then have $X^2 = 0$! Using this "insight", you can actually give the isomorphism you need.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this. Do understand correctly that you mean $X^2∼Y$ ?

Comment: Yes, in the initial ring you set $X^2 \thicksim Y$. Quotienting means that you turn $\thicksim$ into simply $=$.

Comment: @Antoine I think I'm beginning to understand what you mean. But you are using something like $(R/(X^2-Y))/(X^2+Y)= R/(X^2-Y,X^2+Y) $ right ?

Comment: Yes, you can view it as first modding out by the first generator and then by the second. Or modify the above equivalence relation by saying $p \thicksim q$ iff $p = q + R(X^2-Y) \vee p = q + R(X^2+Y)$ to do it simultaneously.

Comment: @karl_christ Thanks! I get it. Can I in general say that for $a,b \in R$, that $(R/(a))/(b)=R/(a,b)$

Comment: @90intuition I think so, yes. Using the third isomorphism theorem as Camilo Arosemena already did, we get in general: $R/(a,b) = (R/(a))/((a,b)/(a)) = (R/(a))/(b)$, since $(a,b)/(a) = (b)$. Keep in mind, that the equality signs are actually an abuse of notation and mean isomorphisms; in your case for example $(\mathbb{C}[X,Y]/(X^2-Y))/(X^2+Y)) = \mathbb C[X]/(X^2+Y)$ doesn't make sense, since $(X^2+Y)$ isn't an ideal in $\mathbb C[X]$. You have to notice, that $(a,b)/(a)$ and $(b)$ are only isomorphic and substitute $Y$ by $X^2$ (@Camilo Arosemena: I now see where you earlier got $2X^2$)

Comment: @karl_christ But if $(a,b)/(a)$ is isomorphic with $(b)$ then $ℤ/7ℤ=(3ℤ+7ℤ)/7ℤ=3ℤ$. But $ℤ/7ℤ$ is finite and $3ℤ$ is infinite. I think it is: $aR+bR/aR = bR/aR = b (R/aR)$ so then you have $(a,b)/(a)=[b]$ where $[b]=b (R/aR)$ the ideal generated in $R/aR$

Comment: @90intuition Yes, I see, that was my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try using the third isomorphism theorem:$$\mathbb C[X,Y]/I≅ \mathbb C[X,Y]/(X^2-Y)/(X^2-Y,X^2+Y)/(X^2-Y)$$$$≅\mathbb C[X]/(X^2).$$

Comment: I can understand that $ℂ[X,Y]/(Y-X^2)= ℂ[X]$ using $R[X]/(X-a)≅R$. How do you get $(X^2-Y,X^2+Y)/(X^2-Y) ≅ (2X^2)$ ?

Comment: @90intuition $(X^2-Y,X^2+Y)/(X^2-Y)≅(X^2)$ as you can define a unique homomorphism of rings $\varphi:\mathbb C[X,Y]\rightarrow\mathbb C[X]$ by $\varphi(X)=X$ and $\varphi(Y)=X^2$, then show that $\ker\varphi=(X^2-Y)$, and that $\varphi[(X^2+Y)]=(X^2)$, so the ring $(X^2+Y,X^2-Y)/(X^2-Y)$ and $(X^2)$ are isomorphic.